# show textbox on radiobutton click django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two radio buttons and on the selection of one radio button i want to show the textbox. if the user selects the radio button with the value of "other" then display the textbox, if its anything else dont display the textbox.

```
apply_type= (
        ('Online',_('Online')),
        ('Others',_('Others')),
    )

how_to_apply =    models.CharField(verbose_name=_('How to Apply'),max_length=255,null=True,    choices=apply_type,default='Online')
```

How can this be done in django?

Comment: This showing thing will have to be done using javascript

Answer (score 0):

One way is to just use javascript client-side to show an input when a certain radio button is checked.

If you want to do it in django, you could use a [`form wizard`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#module-django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views) and have the selections that are made on the first form affect the rest of the forms that are displayed.